# How to forcefully run two thread on two cores

Tags: multi-core

I have a C Code in linux, in which I have two Pthreads. What I have to do is that, I want every thread running on different Cores.

For Example, I have two cores, so one thread should execute on core1 and second thread should execute on core2.

Is there any way like, software or system call to do this?

Comment: Try using [`pthread_setaffinity_np`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

Comment: @muru Can you give me some idea or sample code, so that I could understand how to use it?

Comment: Did you even bother to read the linked page? There's an example in it.

Comment: @CSstudent: Do you have any reason to suspect, that the program only runs on a single core? The thread scheduler of the kernel usually distributes the load evenly among all cores.

Comment: @DavidFoerster During execution, I saw System monitors, which shows only one core is being used.

Comment: I suspect that this is more likely a programming issue. Are you sure, that the program is not only capable to spawn multiple threads but also to run them in parallel? You wouldn't be the first person to accidentally serialise a parallel algorithm.

Comment: @muru: as you used backticks **and** a link, it wasn't obvious that it even *was* a link...  **:P  ;-)**  Also: Me, schmuck, answer etc...  **;-)**